# failed to deploy solana smart contract (solang compiler)

Tags: solidity, solana

I run:

- `Solana-keygen new --force`
- `solana airdrop 5`
- I have a solidity smart contract that looks like this:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract ERC20 {
    
    uint public x = 0;

    constructor() {
        x = 30;
    }
}
```

and I run `solang ERC20.sol --target solana --output build` to compile it for solana from solidity.

As the last step, I am trying to deploy the program:

```
solana program deploy build/bundle.so
```

Problem:

> Error: Deploying program failed: Error processing Instruction 1:
> invalid account data for instruction

Here is the transaction: [Link](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3ZmuDw1NE3VqxtNTBahA9iMNH1gUu2ADpjErLqe7SK8vBJCAxHCjjC3djxh2yhCVcPho5HUsqsLoH6rzDAjL14q9?cluster=devnet)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use the `solana` command line tool to deploy a solidity contract. You can use javascript for now: https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/targets/solana.html

We are considering options for making it easier to use from the command line, but that's in the in planning phase.

Comment: \ SORRY   This page does /

Comment: We've rearranged our documentation, which broke links. :( https://solang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/targets/solana.html